# Switching between activities and fragments in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm not an expert in Android, but really interested in fragments. Would be grateful for your help!

I've implemented a navigation drawer in my app. There is a base drawer activity and a number of fragments a user can switch between from the drawer menu. There is no problem if I want to move to another fragment, but it is working when I use an intent to start a new activity. If you look at my code below you'll see that I use two separate menus: one is for ActionBar icons (cart and search), where intents work perfectly and another one is for Nav drawer to jump between fragments. Is there any way to combine it in one? Basically, I need to move to Profile and Log out activities from nav drawer. Thank you for your advice in advance!

[The screen is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKTHi.png)

**Java file**

```
public class BaseDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_drawer);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        nvDrawer = findViewById(R.id.nvgView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//Menu created for cart and search icons
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        //return true;
    }

//This method is designed only for cart and search icons
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.cart) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.search) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

//This method is to set up the drawer content/menu
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Here we create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
                break;
            case  R.id.nav_cat:
                fragmentClass = CatalogFragment.class;
                break;
            case  R.id.nav_logout:
                fragmentClass = CatalogFragment.class;
                break;

            case R.id.nav_login:
                //what should I add here to be able to move to another activity (not a fragment). It doesn't work when I use intents
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                //need to move to another activity
            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flcontent, fragment).addToBackStack("back tag").commit();

        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // Set action bar title
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        // Close the navigation drawer
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing the same thing you did with the optionItems and preventing the code related to the fragment to be executed when starting an Activity:

```
public class BaseDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_drawer);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    nvDrawer = findViewById(R.id.nvgView);
    // Setup drawer view
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//Menu created for cart and search icons
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //return true;
}

//This method is design only for cart and search icons
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.cart) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CartActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.search) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//This method is to set up the drawer content/menu
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Here we create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
            break;
        case  R.id.nav_cat:
            fragmentClass = CatalogFragment.class;
            break;
        case  R.id.nav_logout:
            fragmentClass = CatalogFragment.class;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_login:
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_profile:
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
             break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
    }
    //Code related to fragment should not execute when choosing to start an Activity     
    if(fragmentClass != null){
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flcontent, fragment).addToBackStack("back tag").commit();

        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
    }
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    // Set action bar title
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    // Close the navigation drawer
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }

}
```